# Add class to link for each div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've this code

```js
$('#parent').each(function(){
  $('#parent p a:not(:has(img))').addClass('happy_cats');
});
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <p><a href="#"><img src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/0079c830-3406-4c05-a5c1-bc43e8f01479/7dd84d70-768b-492b-88f7-a6c70f2db2e9.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a></p>
    <p><a href="#">lol</a><p>
</div>

<div id="parent">
    <p>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/0079c830-3406-4c05-a5c1-bc43e8f01479/7dd84d70-768b-492b-88f7-a6c70f2db2e9.jpg" alt="ddd" width="100" height="100"></a></p>
    <p><a href="#">lol</a><p>
</div>
```

I want to add the class `happy_cats`on links which have no image inside.
I try this code, it's only works on the first div `#parent`

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2):

Use `class` instead of `id`

```
$('.parent').each(function(){
        $('.parent p a:not(:has(img))').addClass('happy_cats');
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <p><a href="#"><img src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/0079c830-3406-4c05-a5c1-bc43e8f01479/7dd84d70-768b-492b-88f7-a6c70f2db2e9.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a></p>
    <p><a href="#">lol</a><p>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <p>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/0079c830-3406-4c05-a5c1-bc43e8f01479/7dd84d70-768b-492b-88f7-a6c70f2db2e9.jpg" alt="ddd" width="100" height="100"></a></p>
    <p><a href="#">lol</a><p>
</div>
```

Comment: It works ! I assume it is because id is unique unlike class

Comment: If it is working for you can check it is as correct. It might help some one else.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
$('[id="parent"]').each(function(){
    $(this).find('p a:not(:has(img))').addClass('happy_cats');
});
```

or probably just

```
$('[id="parent"] p a:not(:has(img))').addClass('happy_cats');
```

`$('#id')` will just find the first match